# Reactivity breaks when changing ref's value inside an asychronous callback

Tags: vuejs3, fullcalendar, pinia, vue-reactivity

Consider the following simple example (vue3 + pinia + fullcalendar):

**the store:**

```
export const useFullCalendarStore = defineStore('calendar', () => {
    // ...
    const activeView = ref<Nullable<ViewApi>>(null);

    const options = reactive<CalendarOptions>({
        datesSet: ({ view }) => {
            nextTick(() => {
                activeView.value = view;
            });
        }
    });
    // ...
});
```

**the component:**

```
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="text-3240 font-bold">{{ viewHeaderTitle }}</div>
    <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useFullCalendarStore } from '@/vue/src/store/FullCalendar';

const _fullCalendarStore = useFullCalendarStore();

const viewHeaderTitle = computed(() => {
    return _fullCalendarStore.activeView?.activeStart.toDateString();
});
</script>
```

Normally each time `activeView` changes the component should be updated but in this case it doesn't because the ref change happens inside the callback function. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

The issue you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of the callback function inside `datesSet`. The reactivity system in Vue doesn't detect changes made inside asynchronous callbacks by default. To make sure that the reactivity works as expected, you can use the `reactive` function from the `@vue/reactivity` module to create a reactive object for your store and then assign values to it. Here's how you can modify your code:

```js
// Import reactive from @vue/reactivity
import { reactive } from '@vue/reactivity';

// ...

export const useFullCalendarStore = defineStore('calendar', () => {
    // ...
    const store = reactive({
        activeView: ref<Nullable<ViewApi>>(null)
    });

    const options = reactive<CalendarOptions>({
        datesSet: ({ view }) => {
            nextTick(() => {
                store.activeView.value = view;
            });
        }
    });
    // ...
});
```

By encapsulating the `activeView` property within a `reactive` object, you ensure that any changes made to it within the asynchronous callback are reactive and will trigger updates in the component.

This change should enable proper reactivity even when modifying `activeView` inside the asynchronous callback.